# annoying overlaps occur when white css text opacity is below 1

Tags: css, text, opacity

There's this really annoying overlap that's happening with my white text when the opacity is below 1 in CSS. It's not major but it's very distracting and I was wondering how I could resolve this so that it flows without this weird overlay. help?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.. If you do not wish to see what is 'under' the semi-transparent layer, why not get the hex for the semi-transparent lettering (gray), and use that as the color. You could also use an image rather than html text, or space the letters out more.

Comment: ah, that's unfortunate. I wanted it transparent because it interacts with images and I wanted the user to see what was behind it. As for the image, when the screen gets smaller, the text gets pushed to the next line so I think an image would solve this but would not allow for the same flexibility--thank you for the reply though!

Comment: You could save the image with transparency as a .png, and accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `letter-spacing` property to spread the letters out more:

```
p
{    
    letter-spacing: 50px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9m5xoL1p/)

Comment: this wouldn't work for this typographically, this is a script font that relies on letters touching--thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

There is really only one way to do this.  You would need to use a program like fireworks or photoshop and transform your text into a solid white .png image with a transparent background.  Then the letters would be one solid color and you could add opacity values to the actual image after placing it in a div. This would eliminate the overlapping issues.  Here's an example with the colors being opposite.  Play with the opacity and you'll see it works. http://jsfiddle.net/eteryrr4/1/

```
.transparent img {
    opacity:.5;
}
```